# How can I fix this ht access file in the cpanel to resolve this Internal Server Error I'm getting

Tags: http, cpanel

So I'm trying to force https on my boss's website, and after watching multiple tutorial videos I was told to edit the htaccess file and paste these 3 lines of code in at the top

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I did this and now I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error. I deleted my changes but I'm still getting this error??

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try using the below code in the .htaccess file?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Is the Boss website using any CMS like WordPress, Magento etc? If yes, then it is a good practise to change the base URL and home URL in the database to https, instead of using the htaccess to force https.